# How to set WebService annotattion with wsdlLocation set to a URL

Tags: java, web-services

I have a WebService class:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface="Test",
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test/",
    wsdlLocation="")
public class TestImpl implements Test{
  //...
}
```

However the `wsdlLocation` only takes a String, but I need to get the wsdl file from a Resource URL:

```
url = getClass().getResource("/wsdl/Test.wsdl");
```

which was packaged in a jar file. How can I properly set the `wsdlLocation` parameter in the annoatation?

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have to use the `wsdlLocation` property in webService annotation, is optional, you can do this

```
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface="Test",
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test/")
public class TestImpl implements Test{
  //...
}
```

And set the url in a properties files or whatever, you can dynamically set the webService URL (and WSDL URL) at runtime in a WebService Client reading it with your preferred method, the way to set the URL will depends on the JAX-WS framework you use.

Comment: So the server side does not need a WSDL file?

Comment: Yes, the server side needs it in order to show it but you don´t need to define it in `wsdlLocation`property, usually web servers or framework stuffs generates automatically the file for you. What framework are you using for WS? What server are you using?

Comment: I am running on JBoss 5

Comment: ok, you should be able to access to the WSDL file typing the service url plus `?WSDL` in a browser without anything else if the web service is correctly deployed, could you test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
wsdlLocation = "file:../wsdl/Test.wsdl"
```

This will look for a test.wsdl file in project files, you just have to correctly point to the file.